# C++ for each, pulling from vector elements

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, each

I am trying to do a foreach on a vector of attacks, each attack has a **unique ID** say, 1-3.

The class method takes the keyboard input of 1-3.

I am trying to use a foreach to run through my elements in m_attack to see if the number matches, if it does... do something.

The problem I'm seeing is this:

```
a'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "std::vector<Attack
```

Am I going about this totally wrong, I have C# experience and is kind of what I'm basing this on, any help would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

In header

```
vector<Attack> m_attack;
```

In class

```
int Player::useAttack (int input)
{

    for each (Attack* attack in m_attack) // Problem part
    {  
        //Psuedo for following action
        if (attack->m_num == input)
        {
            //For the found attack, do it's damage
            attack->makeDamage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the function [std::for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

Comment: A different approach but: `std::map<int, Attack*> attacks;` and in method: `attacks[input]->makeDamage();` (in try catch for `out_of_range` exception).

Answer (score 209, accepted):

For next examples assumed that you use C++11.
Example with ranged-based for loops:

```
for (auto &attack : m_attack) // access by reference to avoid copying
{  
    if (attack.m_num == input)
    {
        attack.makeDamage();
    }
}
```

You should  use `const auto &attack` depending on the behavior of `makeDamage()`.

You can use `std::for_each` from standard  library + lambdas:

```
std::for_each(m_attack.begin(), m_attack.end(),
        [](Attack * attack)
        {
            if (attack->m_num == input)
            {
                attack->makeDamage();
            }
        }
);
```

If you are uncomfortable using `std::for_each`, you can loop over `m_attack` using iterators:

```
for (auto attack = m_attack.begin(); attack != m_attack.end(); ++attack)
{  
    if (attack->m_num == input)
    {
        attack->makeDamage();
    }
}
```

Use `m_attack.cbegin()` and `m_attack.cend()` to get `const` iterators.

Comment: Ah, that's the header I was searching for then, I was hunting libraries for it. Thanks.

Comment: That second one is just what I'm after actually, and more importantly I understand ;).

Thanks for that, that's got it.

Comment: @Justin Shrake : May want to explain why pass by reference is probably (but not always) preferable in ranged for loops, as opposed to pass by copy.

Comment: I'm brushing up on my C++ so if you use a reference, it avoids copying the object in question? What about a pointer?

Comment: In your first example, doesn't `auto& attack` implies `attack.m_num` and `attack.makeDamage()` instead of the arrow notation?

Answer (score 33):

This is how it would be done in a loop in C++(11):

```
   for (const auto& attack : m_attack)
    {  
        if (attack->m_num == input)
        {
            attack->makeDamage();
        }
    }
```

There is no `for each` in C++. Another option is to use [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a suitable functor (this could be anything that can be called with an `Attack*` as argument).

Comment: [`for each`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx) is a supported extension in VS's native c++

Answer (score 12):

The `for each` syntax is supported as an extension to native c++ in Visual Studio.

The example provided in [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int total = 0;

  vector<int> v(6);
  v[0] = 10; v[1] = 20; v[2] = 30;
  v[3] = 40; v[4] = 50; v[5] = 60;

  for each(int i in v) {
    total += i;
  }

  cout << total << endl;
}
```

(works in VS2013) is not portable/cross platform but gives you an idea of how to use `for each`.

The standard alternatives (provided in the rest of the answers) apply everywhere. And it would be best to use those.

Answer (score 6):

C++ does not have the `for_each` loop feature in its syntax. You have to use c++11 or use the template function `std::for_each`.

```
struct Function {
    int input;
    Function(int input): input(input) {}
    void operator()(Attack& attack) {
        if(attack->m_num == input) attack->makeDamage();
    }
};
Function f(input);
std::for_each(m_attack.begin(), m_attack.end(), f);
```

Comment: This is such a help thanks, I've almost got it working but I need to make it return an int for the method.

I'm trying, I have tried but can't work out how to do reference the pointer in the correct place on a return, could you possibly edit your answer to help with that?

Comment: @Springfox You can add extra member variables to the struct if needed and access them later using f.method(...);

Comment: why not std::begin/std::end on m_attack?

Comment: [`for each`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx) is a supported extension in VS's native c++