# How to use for each loop in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str("hello world!");
    for (auto &c : str)
        c = toupper(c);
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

This c++ code does not compile.
Error msg:
    main.cpp:21: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ':' token
Question:
Is there a for each loop in c++ (range for loop?)?
what is wrong with the for each loop above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It exists in C++11. Make sure you use a compiler that can handle C++11, and make sure you enable the required options for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15027282/62576

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code is valid, as can be demonstrated on an [online compiler](http://ideone.com/msj6Ai).

Please refer to your compiler documentation to be sure you have enabled C++11. The option is often called `-std=c++11`. You might have to download an upgrade; check your package manager for GCC (currently at 4.8) or Clang (currently 3.3).

Answer (score 4):

Prior to C++11x, `for_each` is defined in the `algorithm` header.
Simply use:

```
for_each (vec.begin(), vec.end(), fn);
```

where `fn` is a function to which the element will be passed, and the first two arguments are input iterators.

Also, after including both `string` and `algorithm` you could just use

`std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(),str.begin(), ::toupper);`

Comment: `std::for_each` is still defined in the `algorithm` header, even in C++11. (The range-based for-loop introduced by C++11 into the language core has not replaced the `std::for_each` algorithm, even though there is some overlap in the use cases.)